# Plan 9 sam comment and copy line

Tags: regex

Using plan 9's sam, how would I change something like

```
foo->bar
```

to

```
//foo->bar
foo->baz
```

for every ocourance of `foo->bar` in the file

clarification:

I want the pattern to be able to be anywhere in the line

eg:
    if (foo->bar)

to

```
//if (foo->baz)
if (foo->bar)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only help you with the regex part, since I am not familiar with the Sam Text editor.

Find: foo->bar
Replace with: //foo-bar\r\nfoo-baz

Since you are working in a unix environment, you might want to replace with:
//foo-bar\nfoo-baz

So a "unix" line-end instead of a "windows" line-end.

For information on how to use regex in Sam, i suggest you just consult the manual, or any tutorial you can (probably?) find through google.